# RestClient DELETE Operation Json Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a Delete action with RestClient but I'm not able to include my Json object inside the request body. This is my code:

```
        var client = new RestClient(WebService);
        var request = new RestRequest(string.Format("/api/v1/{0}/{1}", controller,    action), method);

        request.AddHeader("Accept", ContentTypeApplicationJson);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;            
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", ContentTypeApplicationJson);
        request.AddCookie(".ASPXAUTH", AspxAuth);
        request.AddBody(jsonObjectRequest);

        var response = client.Execute(request);

        var jsonResponse = string.Empty;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(response.RawBytes))
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var jObjectDeserialize = GetJObjectDeserialize(jsonResponse);
```

In my example ContentTypeApplicationJson = application/json and jsonObject is a object which contain:

{
  "BasketItemReferenceGuid": "sample string 1",
  "BasketReferenceGuid": "sample string 2"
}

This is my request in Fiddler

```
DELETE http://local.webapi.com/api/v1/BasketV3Products/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: RestSharp 102.4.0.0
Host: local.webapi.com
Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=E6D216034E2CB1A22466A501392B1E2E46601E345B8A0E7743D76CF2270ACFC8ED3C9F1F2F477C4499267222A250E4490291381EE68FE719E094EF1ACDD619B4D792341988F80CB67E8B5037D8ACF9FBABB74DE1E75A530AB432D85722D647771C6C576F8E810257CE9E60117DCEEFBD949EAD9E64C84898BDC5D691F957CE6266CF5652C693B86ED1D55907AAC5DC68
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like even though the HTTP spec doesn't explicitly say that a `DELETE` should not have a body, many web servers (or web proxies) will ignore it.

Semantically, when using `DELETE`, the uri should identify the resource to `DELETE`.  This is kind of like using `GET`.  Again, with `GET`, the spec does not forbid a body, but not many web servers (or web proxies) actually support a body on `GET` requests.

For more info, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request).

So, the better way to implement your `DELETE` would be to place `BasketItemReferenceGuid` and `BasketReferenceGuid` in the uri template.

Comment: Hi, Davin. Thank you for your answer. Finally I resolved the problem makin the request with HttpWebRequest. By this way, you can include whatever you want inside DELETE request body. Thanks